# http запросы на java

Tags: java, сервер, асинхронность

Подскажите, я правильно понимаю, что http запросы работают по принципу один запрос - один ответ, и даже в том случае, если множественные запросы поступают на сервер асинхронно, и, соответственно, ответы мы тоже получаем асинхронно, нет нужды каждому запросу присваивать идентификатор, поскольку путаницы все равно не произойдет, и мы на каждый запрос получим ответ, направленный на этот конкретный запрос?
Или все же идентифицировать запросы надо, чтобы не возникло путаницы?

Comment: Это задача протокола http, Вы наверняка знаете на какой запрос пришел ответ.

Comment: Поместить идентификатор в запрос. Наверно будет самый лучший способ идентифицировать запросы.

Comment: Stranger in the Q говорит - это задача HTTP, Roman C говорит - надо явно указать идентификатор. И кто в итоге прав?)